# Updating domain instances in beforeUpdate method calling the method infinitely

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class and I need to update some values of other instances of the same domain on `updateBofore` method. But it is going to be run infinitely. Is there any way to update only once?

```
Class ABC {

    String name
    String ref

    def beforeUpdate() {
        List abcs = findAllWhere(ref: ref)
        abcs.each {
            it.name = name
            it.save(flush: true)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it any reason because you can not use beforeInsert?

Comment: No I just want to update all the objects of ABC domain with same ref value on any of them update.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `beforeUpdate` method like:

```
def beforeUpdate() {
    def currentInstance = this

    ABC.withNewSession {
        List abcs = ABC.withCriteria {
            eq("ref", currentInstance.ref)
            // Make sure we don't again update the same current instance
            ne("id", currentInstance.id)
        }

        abcs.each {
            it.name = currentInstance.name
            it.save(flush: true)
        }
    }
}
```

The two things are changed in your `beforeUpdate` method:

1. Using `withNewSession` so that the new `save()` operation should not try to flush the current hibernate session (which would result in infinite  loop)
2. Using `ne()` criteria to exclude the current instance from being updated since you are already updating the current instance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the before insert gorm event without iterating all list and calling save.

```
class ABC {
    //your defs here

    def beforeInsert() 
        List abcs = findAllWhere(ref: ref) 
        if(abcs){
          this.name = abcs.first().name
        }
    }
}
```

You have to call save outside the domain class

```
ABC a = new ABC()
a.save()
```

And the beforeInsert make the trick